# Uso do ks.test para distribuição Poisson

Tags: r

Boa noite, pessoal.
Estou com uma dúvida quanto a utilização da função ks.test.

Está dando resultados completamente diferentes quando utilizo o ks.test especificando a distribuição de probabilidade:

```
ks.test (amostra$x,"ppois",lambda=mean(amostra$x))
```

E comparando a minha amostra de interesse com uma amostra gerada a partir da rpois:

```
ks.test (amostra$x,rpois(length(amostra$x),mean(amostra$x)))
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse impasse, por gentileza ?

Comment: O teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov é para distribuições contínuas,não para a distribuição de Poisson. Para a Poisson, experimente o `chisq.test`.